# shadowing a site module by my own module in Python

Tags: python, python-import

I have a script `foo.py`, which tries to `from bar import baz`: basically the hierarchy is the following:

```
/
    foo.py
    bar/
        __init__.py
        baz.py
```

The problem is that the system ships its own version of `bar` in `site-packages`, and I want to avoid importing that (I want to make sure I use the module I ship instead of whatever version might be on the system).

Initially I thought that the order of the paths in `sys.path` will be enough to solve the problem. However, on some systems, there's a `bar.pth` file in `site-packages` that adds `bar` to `sys.modules`, which results in ignoring `sys.path` completely when importing `bar` and just importing the `site-packages` version.

How can I make sure that I import my local version of `bar`, regardless of what might be set up on the system?

Comment: Just rename `bar`. Shadowing a built-in module like this is a horrible idea. It doesn't just affect your own code, like shadowing `list`; it affects all code in the entire program.

Comment: This is not built-in module, this is a module in site-packages. I cannot rename bar -- it's the same module as the system one, just possibly different version.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html), if you define an environment variable, `PYTHONPATH`, which contains the folder `bar`, that will be tried first, and thus it will import your module.

Comment: This doesn't help -- if `bar.pth` adds the module to `sys.modules`, it won't even search the import path when trying to import `bar.baz`, as it will first find `bar` in `sys.modules`, and use `bar.__path__` to import `bar.baz`

Comment: I see, have you tried simply deleting this module from `sys.modules`? E.g.  del sys.modules[′bar′] and then importing your own with the right precedence in the search path? Although it is a strong `code smell` in my opinion: built-in modules should be left alone.

Comment: Deleting module from sys.modules might help, but I want to have a more robust method that will deal with all possible quirks of Python import system (e.g. sys.meta_path etc).